# Filter object array to return the object with the latest date property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

If I have an object array like this :

```
var array = [
  {
    "id": 5,
    "date": "2016-01-15T16:18:44.258843Z",
    "status": "NEW",
    "created_at": "2016-01-29T13:30:39.315000Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-01-29T13:30:39.315000Z",
    "request": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "date": "2016-01-19T16:18:44.258843Z",
    "status": "STD",
    "created_at": "2016-01-29T13:30:39.372000Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-01-29T13:30:39.372000Z",
    "request": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "date": "2016-01-23T16:18:44.258843Z",
    "status": "FOR",
    "created_at": "2016-01-29T13:30:39.417000Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-01-29T13:30:39.417000Z",
    "request": 4
  }];
```

how can I filter it in order to only return the element (object) with the latest property `date` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function:

without null checking you can simply use

```
array.sort((a,b) => new Date(b.date).getTime() - new Date(a.date).getTime())[0];
```

Comment: Thanks, but for the latest date, shouldn't it be `b - a` instead of `a - b` ?

Answer (score 17):

Just use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and return the object with the latest date (while you have an ISO date, you can compare it directly):

```js
var array = [{ "id": 5, "date": "2016-01-15T16:18:44.258843Z", "status": "NEW", "created_at": "2016-01-29T13:30:39.315000Z", "updated_at": "2016-01-29T13:30:39.315000Z", "request": 4 }, { "id": 6, "date": "2016-01-19T16:18:44.258843Z", "status": "STD", "created_at": "2016-01-29T13:30:39.372000Z", "updated_at": "2016-01-29T13:30:39.372000Z", "request": 4 }, { "id": 7, "date": "2016-01-23T16:18:44.258843Z", "status": "FOR", "created_at": "2016-01-29T13:30:39.417000Z", "updated_at": "2016-01-29T13:30:39.417000Z", "request": 4 }],
    latest = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r.date > a.date ? r : a;
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(latest, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Excellent answer...I was having an issue with comparing date strings and date objects and I was able to use a modified version to get it working properly:  array.reduce((r, a) => new Date(r.date) > new Date(a.date) ? r : a);

Answer (score 3):

Try that:

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
        return Date.parse(a.date) - Date.parse(b.date);
   });
```